# How to load an Angular2 component directly on the index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have the following project:

```
$ mkdir angular-material-select
$ cd angular-material-select
$ git clone https://github.com/zeuscronos/angular-material-select.git .
$ git checkout mat-slide-toggle 
$ npm install
$ ng serve
```

Please, notice the selection of branch: `mat-slide-toggle`.

I need to be able to load the component: `mat-slide-toggle` from the `/src/index.html` file.

In the file: `/src/app/app.module.ts` I have the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectResetExample } from './select-reset-example';
import { DemoMaterialModule } from './demomaterial.module';
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        DemoMaterialModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    entryComponents: [MatSlideToggle],
    declarations: [MatSlideToggle],
    bootstrap: [MatSlideToggle],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the file: `/src/index.html` I have the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularTemplate</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
        <mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the structure of the project:

[image]

The project I have on the branch: `master` works properly, but inside the `/src/index.html` file it is using: `<select-reset-example>loading</select-reset-example>` and I want to use: `<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>`. Below, you have the changes I did from branch: `master` to branch: `mat-slide-toggle`:

[image]

as you can see [here](https://github.com/zeuscronos/angular-material-select/commit/3f5aa9f8f471f5de8ee2fb95478dbf211a701380).

Then, when I run the example above with:

`$ ng serve`

I only get the inner html content I put inside the `mat-slide-toggle` component:

`Slide me!`

So, it doesn't work.

Any idea on how to make this work?

**[begin of edition 1]**

I'm working on this:

Original (working):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-5we8sr?file=index.html

Modified based on @Asura comment (not working):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-k2isdx?file=main.ts

**[end of edition 1]**

Thanks.

Comment: whay do you want to use the same in index.html .The index.html is the page where your app is bootstrapped and you loads all your SPA contents there

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the module MatSlideToggleModule instead of MatSlideToggle
in order to be able to use mat-slide-toggle

https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktmgc-bazda7

Comment: I did that modification but didn't work. Could you check the **edition 1** on my post above?. If possible could you do a fork on: `stackblitz.com` with a working configuration?. Thanks!

Comment: but on the `index.html` file you are not using: `<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>` as I need. You are using: `<select-reset-example>loading</select-reset-example>` instead.

Comment: select-reset-example is using mat-slide-toggle its its component html.